# I tripled check every details and even though smtplib is not working

Tags: python, email, smtplib

```
import smtplib

myemail = "sender@gmail.com"



password_code = "ieruweioruiweoru"
with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com") as connection:
    connection.starttls()
    connection.login(user=myemail, password=password_code)
    connection.sendmail(from_addr=myemail, to_addrs="reciever@gmail.com", msg="this is body")
```

I tirple check all things from password to email. the smtplib is installed in my machine.In response I got this:
`TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond`

I wanted to sent the email succesfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**:

Define the port number. By default it is set to 25 but modern email providers will be using port 587.
Change

```
with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com") as connection
```

to

```
with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com",587) as connection
```

Comment: Well, to be more accurate, "port 587 is used for TLS connections".  Modern email providers must and do handle port 25, but not for secured connections.